# Ошибка при установке WordPress на сервер

Tags: wordpress, установка

Подскажите, что может означать такая ошибка при установке WP

> PHP Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '.../wp-includes/pomo/mo.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   .../www/wp-settings.php on line 76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите, что может означать такая ошибка

означает она, что скрипт `./www/wp-settings.php` не может найти файл `./wp-includes/pomo/mo.php`

Comment: Верно. Архив с вордпресом криво скачался, не со всеми файлами. Спасибо!